# Electron window dragging incompatible with titleBarOverlay

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

When Electron BrowserWindow is configured with `titleBarOverlay`, elements with CSS property `-webkit-app-region: drag` are not dragging the window anymore (this is working well without `titleBarOverlay`).

The issue seems to be only on Windows (it is working well on MacOS).

Do you have any clue about this issue? Thank you!

**app-process.js:**

```js
  const window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 700,
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    titleBarOverlay: {
      color: '#1D1D1D',
      symbolColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      webviewTag: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });
```

**TopBar:**

```html
<nav style="-webkit-app-region: drag; -webkit-app-select:none;">
  ...
</nav>
```

Comment: What version of Electron are you using? I have tested your code on Windows 10 with Electron  ^18.0.0 and it works.